# Changing CSS style depending on the model value

Tags: css, sapui5

I would like to use an icon and change the color depending on the model.

```
var wirelessHeadItem = new sap.ui.unified.ShellHeadItem({
    icon: "sap-icon://upload-to-cloud"
});
```

How can I define the color of the icon to something like this:

```
style: "color:{/oSettingsModel/isOnline}"
```

That way the icon would change in color, when I change isOnline in the oSettingsModel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, seems that this control does not have either a possibility to specify the color via standard property, therefore you can apply the workaround using [custom data attribute](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1ef9fefa2a574735957dcf52502ab8d0.html) and [expression binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html).

The main point is that you can specify the **writeToDom** attribute of the custom data item, and in your CSS you can define the style for the needed HTML attribute value: *data-color-green* or *data-color-red*.

JS:

```
var wirelessHeadItem = new sap.ui.unified.ShellHeadItem({
    icon: "sap-icon://upload-to-cloud",
    customData: [
        new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
            key: "color",
            value: "{= ${/oSettingsModel/isOnline} ? 'green' : 'red' }",
            writeToDom: true
        });
    ]
});
```

CSS might look like this:

```
div[data-color=green] {
  color: green;
}
div[data-color=red] {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easier way is put it in a hbox and set the class="colorCode"
in the css file, set the class color