# SAPUI5: How can i add a different css class to each FeedList Item?

Tags: sapui5

I Need to add a different css class to each **FeedListItem**.

I need it to added to each class separately & dynamically (onPost method in JS file) since i'm adding different class according to the feed input entered.

I'v checked the sapui5 guide line but i see no property of FeedListItem related to styling&CSS.

**Wanted result:**

```
<ul> //FeedListItems
  <li class="<MY_CUTOM_CLASS_1>"></li>
  <li class="<MY_CUTOM_CLASS_2>"></li>
  <li class="<MY_CUTOM_CLASS_3>"></li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to do it?

**How can i do that?**

XML file:

```
<FeedInput
    post="onPost"
    icon="test-resources/sap/m/images/dronning_victoria.jpg"
    class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" />
<List
    showSeparators="Inner"
    items="{/EntryCollection}" >
    <FeedListItem
        sender="{Author}"
        icon="{AuthorPicUrl}"
        senderPress="onSenderPress"
        iconPress="onIconPress"
        iconDensityAware="false"
        info="{Type}"
        timestamp="{Date}"
        text="{Text}" />
</List>
```

JS file:

```
sap.ui.define([
    'jquery.sap.global',
    'sap/m/MessageToast',
    'sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat',
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
    'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
], function(jQuery, MessageToast, DateFormat, Controller, JSONModel) {
"use strict";

var CController = Controller.extend("sap.m.sample.Feed.C", {

    onInit: function () {
        // set mock model
        var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.m.sample.Feed", "/feed.json")
        var oModel = new JSONModel(sPath);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    },

    onPost: function (oEvent) {
        var oFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({style: "medium"});
        var oDate = new Date();
        var sDate = oFormat.format(oDate);
        // create new entry
        var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
        var oEntry = {
            Author : "Alexandrina Victoria",
            AuthorPicUrl : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Dronning_victoria.jpg",
            Type : "Reply",
            Date : "" + sDate,
            Text : sValue
        };

        // update model
        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        var aEntries = oModel.getData().EntryCollection;
        aEntries.unshift(oEntry);
        oModel.setData({
            EntryCollection : aEntries
        });
    }   });


return CController;
```

});

Comment: addstyleclass to a feedlistitem. access this class in your css. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.FeedListItem.html

Comment: Can you write how to implement it according to my description?

Answer (score 0):

edit: up to version 1.48 it's not possbile to set a binding to the property "class". however "addStyleClass" and this [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675986/sapui5-changing-color-of-icon/44676649#44676649) work out.

i'm afk and therefore can't validate the following. but this should solve it. in the xml view is the property "class" to add to the feedlistitem. in the js controller the property to the object "oEntry". and the model needs to handle the class attribute as well.

xml view:

```
<FeedInput
  post="onPost"
  icon="test-resources/sap/m/images/dronning_victoria.jpg"
  class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" />
<List
  showSeparators="Inner"
  items="{/EntryCollection}">
  <FeedListItem

    class="{Class}"

    sender="{Author}"
    icon="{AuthorPicUrl}"
    senderPress="onSenderPress"
    iconPress="onIconPress"
    iconDensityAware="false"
    info="{Type}"
    timestamp="{Date}"
    text="{Text}" />
</List>
```

controller js:

```
onPost: function (oEvent) {
  var oFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({style: "medium"});
  var oDate = new Date();
  var sDate = oFormat.format(oDate);
  // create new entry
  var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
  var oEntry = {

    Class: "CSSClass",

    Author : "Alexandrina Victoria",
    AuthorPicUrl : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Dronning_victoria.jpg",
    Type : "Reply",
    Date : "" + sDate,
      Text : sValue
    };
    // update model
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    var aEntries = oModel.getData().EntryCollection;
    aEntries.unshift(oEntry);
    oModel.setData({
      EntryCollection : aEntries
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but it renders <li class="{Class}"></li>... i need it to render value dinamically

Comment: which attribute is supposed to determine which class a feedlistitem should have?

Comment: let's say that i retrieve  a value in onPost() method, and that value is supposed to be the css class attached.

Comment: 1. retrieve in the controller the value in onPost(): "CSSClassName", 2. add in the controller the value "CSSClassName" to oEntry.Class: var oEntry = { Class: "CSSClassName" ...}, 3. receive in the xml view in the feedlistitem the value "CSSClassName" with the binding class="{Class}"

Comment: the property "css" of a control is not bindable, you can only set it once from a view. If you want it "dynamic" you should either use "addStyleClass" method from controller or utilize the workaround using "customData" with "writeToDom" parameter.

Comment: I'm afraid it wont work since i still get  <li class="{Class}"></li>.... i need it to get <li class="CSSClassName"></li>

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych to clarify it for myself: you can't set a binding for the property "class"? and if so, why?

Comment: @n01dea I have n01dea why ui5 devs have not made the "class" as usual property that can be bound.. I cannot find this in documentation. This is so irritating, because it is very often when this functionality is really needed.

Comment: @Eli sorry, this solution won't work because of the reason stated above. would go instead with the addstyleclass as suggested.

Comment: @Eli or if you still want to rule over this thing dynamically & declaratively, you can use the "customData" workaround, here is my past answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675986/sapui5-changing-color-of-icon/44676649#44676649

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych take my upvote for that and congratulations to > 500 ; )